# Materialize Datepicker without modal?

Tags: css, materialize

Materialize's Datepicke rmakes use of modal (popup).

http://materializecss.com/forms.html#date-picker

Is there a way to use Materialize's Datepicker, without the modal (popup), like embed it to the webpage instead? If possible how can I achieve that?

Comment: Has the same idea, did you solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do couple of things, such as:

1) Set the container to match the element you want datepicker to be embedded into. Materialize Datepicker has that option. See [the docs](https://materializecss.com/pickers.html).

2) Override .modal-overlay class and set its **display** property to **none**

3) Override .modal class by setting its **position** to **relative** and **margin** to **0**

4) Override .datepicker class by setting **visibility** to **hidden** and **position** to **fixed** in order to hide the **input** element

The rest is up to you. But it's all about playing with CSS

EDIT: Also you will probably need to make sure that Datepicker is always open